# Merging two applications using tk frames

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a memory game made with python and tkinter. I've also made an application with a simple GUI that uses tk.Frame to show different frames. My problem is putting the memory game in one of the frames of the GUI app.

I have one .py file for the memory game and one for the GUI. The GUI has multiple classes and frames. I want to put the memory game inside one of those frames so that you can navigate through the menu into the game. The game should only show when navigated to.

I have tried:

- importing the memorygame file at the top of the GUI file
- importing the memorygame file inside a class of the GUI file
- copying the whole memorygame code into a class of the GUI file

Importing the file made both the applications try to run on startup in different windows. Copying the game code into a GUI class gave lots of errors.

I have python 3.7 and tkinter 8.6

The memory game starts by creating a canvas that it draws upon:

```
win = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(win, width = 600, height = 480)
canvas.pack()
class Tile(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, text):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.text = text
    def drawFaceDown(self):
        canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 100, self.y + 100, fill = "green")
...
```

And this is how I use a class to create a frame where I display different things:

```
class PageMG(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # memory game goes here
```

I can show the entire files if anyone wants to see

I want the game to only show until I click on a button that takes me to the frame where I want the game.

Edit: the whole memory game file

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from random import randint
from random import shuffle
win = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(win, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()
class Tile(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, text):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.text = text
    def drawFaceDown(self):
        canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 70, self.y + 70, fill = "blue")
        self.isFaceUp = False
    def drawFaceUp(self):
        canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 70, self.y + 70, fill = "blue")
        canvas.create_text(self.x + 35, self.y + 35, text = self.text, width = 70, fill = "white", font='Helvetica 12 bold')
        self.isFaceUp = True
    def isUnderMouse(self, event):
        if(event.x > self.x and event.x < self.x + 70):
            if(event.y > self.y and event.y < self.y + 70):
                return True

tiles = []
colors = [
    "Eple",
    "Appelsin",
    "Banan",
    "Agurk",
    "Brokkoli",
    "Tomat",
    "Sitron",
    "Melon",
    "Hvitløk",
    "Erter",
    "Jordbær",
    "Blåbær"
]

selected = []
for i in range(10):
    randomInd = randint(0, len(colors) - 1)
    color = colors[randomInd]
    selected.append(color)
    selected.append(color)
    del colors[randomInd]
shuffle(selected)

flippedTiles = []

def mouseClicked(self):
    global numFlipped
    global flippedTiles
    for i in range(len(tiles)):
        if tiles[i].isUnderMouse(self):
            if (len(flippedTiles) < 2 and not(tiles[i].isFaceUp)) :
                tiles[i].drawFaceUp()
                flippedTiles.append(tiles[i])
            if (len(flippedTiles) == 2):
                if not(flippedTiles[0].text == flippedTiles[1].text):
                    time.sleep(1)
                    flippedTiles[0].drawFaceDown()
                    flippedTiles[1].drawFaceDown()

NUM_COLS = 5
NUM_ROWS = 4

for x in range(0,NUM_COLS):
    for y in range(0,NUM_ROWS):
            tiles.append(Tile(x * 78 + 10, y * 78 + 40, selected.pop()))

for i in range(len(tiles)):
    tiles[i].drawFaceDown()

flippedThisTurn = 0
def mouseClicked(event):
    global flippedTiles
    global flippedThisTurn
    for tile in tiles:
        if tile.isUnderMouse(event):
            if (not(tile.isFaceUp)) :
                tile.drawFaceUp()
                flippedTiles.append(tile)
                flippedThisTurn += 1

            if (flippedThisTurn == 2):
                win.after(1000, checkTiles)
                flippedThisTurn = 0

def checkTiles():
    if not(flippedTiles[-1].text == flippedTiles[-2].text): #check last two elements
        flippedTiles[-1].drawFaceDown() #facedown last two elements
        flippedTiles[-2].drawFaceDown()
        del flippedTiles[-2:] #remove last two elements

win.bind("<Button-1>", mouseClicked)


win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. importing the memorygame file at the top of the GUI file
> 2. importing the memorygame file inside a class of the GUI file

Both these ways will make "both the applications try to run on startup in different windows" this is because the memorygame file makes a new `tk.Tk()` window, and so does your GUI handler.

> copying the whole memorygame code into a class of the GUI file

This could cause many problems, depending where you copy the files to, since these files have their own import dependencies and the import paths may change depending where you copy the files to.

What I would suggest doing is the following, I would change your code of the memory game to make the memory game a `class(tk.Frame)` (Frame class), then you should be able to import the memory game and stick that frame into the GUI `PageMk(tk.Frame)`, I do not know the dependencies your code has, but this should work.

> Example of change using the provided code

```py
class MemGame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MemGame, self).__init__(parent)
        self.configure(width=600, height=480)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=600, height=480, bg="red")
        canvas.pack()

class Tile:
    def __init__(self, parent, x, y, text):
        self.parent = parent
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.text = text
    def drawFaceDown(self):
        self.parent.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 100, self.y + 100, fill="green")

class PageMG(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        x = MemGame(self)
        x.pack()
```

> My Edits to the full code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time
from random import randint
from random import shuffle


class Controller(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        if True:
            self.frames = {}
            for F in (PageMG,):
                page_name = F.__name__
                frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
                self.frames[page_name] = frame

                # put all of the pages in the same location;
                # the one on the top of the stacking order
                # will be the one that is visible.
                frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            self.show_frame("PageMG")
        self.geometry("500x400")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class PageMG(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        x = MemGame(self)
        x.pack()


class Tile(object):
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, text):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.text = text

    def drawFaceDown(self):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 70, self.y + 70, fill = "blue")
        self.isFaceUp = False

    def drawFaceUp(self):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 70, self.y + 70, fill = "blue")
        self.canvas.create_text(self.x + 35, self.y + 35, text = self.text, width = 70, fill = "white", font='Helvetica 12 bold')
        self.isFaceUp = True

    def isUnderMouse(self, event):
        if(event.x > self.x and event.x < self.x + 70):
            if(event.y > self.y and event.y < self.y + 70):
                return True


class MemGame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(MemGame, self).__init__(master)
        self.configure(width=500, height=500)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=500, height=500)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.tiles = []
        self.colors = [
            "Eple",
            "Appelsin",
            "Banan",
            "Agurk",
            "Brokkoli",
            "Tomat",
            "Sitron",
            "Melon",
            "Hvitløk",
            "Erter",
            "Jordbær",
            "Blåbær"
        ]

        selected = []
        for i in range(10):
            randomInd = randint(0, len(self.colors) - 1)
            color = self.colors[randomInd]
            selected.append(color)
            selected.append(color)
            del self.colors[randomInd]
        shuffle(selected)
        self.flippedTiles = []
        NUM_COLS = 5
        NUM_ROWS = 4

        for x in range(0, NUM_COLS):
            for y in range(0, NUM_ROWS):
                self.tiles.append(Tile(self.canvas, x * 78 + 10, y * 78 + 40, selected.pop()))

        for i in range(len(self.tiles)):
            self.tiles[i].drawFaceDown()
        self.flippedThisTurn = 0
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.mouseClicked)

    # def mouseClicked(self):
    #     for i in range(len(self.tiles)):
    #         if self.tiles[i].isUnderMouse(self):
    #             if (len(self.flippedTiles) < 2 and not(self.tiles[i].isFaceUp)) :
    #                 self.tiles[i].drawFaceUp()
    #                 self.flippedTiles.append(self.tiles[i])
    #             if (len(self.flippedTiles) == 2):
    #                 if not(self.flippedTiles[0].text == self.flippedTiles[1].text):
    #                     time.sleep(1)
    #                     self.flippedTiles[0].drawFaceDown()
    #                     self.flippedTiles[1].drawFaceDown()

    def mouseClicked(self, event):
        for tile in self.tiles:
            if tile.isUnderMouse(event):
                if (not(tile.isFaceUp)) :
                    tile.drawFaceUp()
                    self.flippedTiles.append(tile)
                    self.flippedThisTurn += 1

                if (self.flippedThisTurn == 2):
                    self.after(1000, self.checkTiles)
                    self.flippedThisTurn = 0

    def checkTiles(self):
        if not(self.flippedTiles[-1].text == self.flippedTiles[-2].text): #check last two elements
            self.flippedTiles[-1].drawFaceDown()
            self.flippedTiles[-2].drawFaceDown()
            del self.flippedTiles[-2:]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Controller()
    c.mainloop()
```

Goodluck :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I wll try this later and report back with the results :)

Comment: @Nello I edited my answer, adding an example of how I would edit your code to do what I explained. Hope that helps

Comment: I tried following your suggestion but I got an error message when trying to run the game app with the new edits: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

The error appears in what seems like unrelated code so i'm not sure why it occurs. Would you like to see the whole file?

Comment: I'm happy to have a quick skim over the file, all that error means is that you have a class that requires a text element and isn't being parsed one.

Comment: Great :) I made the MemGame and Tile classes like you did and replaced all instances of 'canvas' with self.parent' in the MemGame class. Then I tried to run the program and got the aforementioned error on line 71: 'tiles.append(Tile(x * 78 + 10, y * 78 + 40, selected.pop()))'

Comment: I have been able to make the code fit into the window. However now that it is in the window, your `mouseClicked()` and `isUnderMouse()` functions do not, work, I do not know how you would fix this. But I have put the window into a "simple gui" like class, in a page class you gave. I'll add my code to my answer, and see what you can do with it.

Comment: It opened just like I wanted to in my GUI so this is great help, thank you very much! I'm sure I can figure out how to fix the problematic functions. I'll mark the question as answered :)